# saved settings in jquery plugin returns undefined inside jquery plugin function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to access saved settings inside a jquery plugin. I have a list of setting I save inside the jquery data. I want to access those setting later on in a  function contained in the plugin.  Code for the plugin below.

```
(function ($) {
    var kendoEditWindowFunctions = {
        init: function (settings) {
            settings.validator = 
 $(this).kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
        $(this).data("settings", settings);
        $(settings.submitButton).click(function () {
            $(settings.Name).kendoEditWindow("Submit");
        });
    },

    OnBegin: function () {
        $(this).addClass("k-state-submit");
    },

    OnComplete: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("k-state-submit");
    },

    OnFailed: function (xhr) {
        AjaxErroMessage(data);
    },

    OnSuccess: function () {
        var settings = $(this).data("settings");
        if (settings.grid)
            $(settings.grid).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        $(this).kendoEditWindow("Close");
        notification.show({
            title: "Success",
            message: "Record has been saved successfully."
        }, "success");
    },

    Open: function (routeValues, e) {
        var settings = $(this).data("settings");
        var url = settings.fetchController + "/" + settings.fetchAction;
        if ($(e.currentTarget).data("grid-button")) {
            var grid = $(e.currentTarget).closest(".k-grid");
            var attributes = $(e.currentTarget).data();
            var uid = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr").data("uid");
            var dataItems = $(grid).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(uid);
            for (var key in attributes) {
                if (attributes.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.indexOf("editRouteProperty") >= 0) {
                    for (var key2 in attributes[key]) {
                        if (attributes[key].hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
                            routeValues[key2] = dataItems[attributes[key][key2]];
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: routeValues,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(settings.window).addClass("k-state-loading");
            },
            complete: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(settings.window).removeClass("k-state-loading");
                }, 500);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $(settings.window).find(".form-container").html(data);


            },
            error: function () {
                $(settings.window).find(".form-container").html("Data load error");
            }

        });

        $(settings.window).data("kendoWindow").open();
    },

    Close: function () {
        $(this).data("kendoWindow").close();
    },

    Clear: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("k-state-submit");
        $(this).removeClass("k-state-loading");
        $(this).find(".form-container").html("");
    },

    Submit: function () {
        var settings = $(this).data("settings");
        if (settings.validator.validate())
            $(settings.form).submit();
    }
}

$.fn.kendoEditWindow = function (methodOrOptions) {
    if (kendoEditWindowFunctions[methodOrOptions]) {
        return kendoEditWindowFunctions[methodOrOptions].apply(this, 
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof methodOrOptions === "object" || !methodOrOptions) {
            return kendoEditWindowFunctions.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error("Method " + methodOrOptions + " does not exist");
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

The issue is that $(this).data("settings") returns undefined inside the Submit function.  I cannot figure out why.  It works just fine in all the other functions but except the submit function.  I am sure it is something really simple.  Any ideas?

Comment: How are you using the Submit method? Have you checked what `this` is when it is called?  Create a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: @charlietfl Look in the "init" function.  I add an event to a button that calls the submit function

Comment: It has something to do with setting the submit button event handler, and using that function to call the submit function. If I call the function from the console itself it works just fine.  I could simply add ht function call directly to the button using the "onclick" attribute, but I wanted to avoid this in order to keep these functions hidden from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `$(settings.Name)` is not the same element that you originally initialized the plugin with

So when you do `$(settings.Name).kendoEditWindow("Submit");` the plugin will have a different `this` that doesn't have any of the data set in it as the original element that the `init()` was applied to

You could try changing

```
$(settings.submitButton).click(function () {
    $(settings.Name).kendoEditWindow("Submit");
});
```

To

```
var _this = this
$(settings.submitButton).click(function () {
   $(_this).kendoEditWindow("Submit");
});
```

Or

```
$(settings.submitButton).click(function () {
    kendoEditWindowFunctions.Submit()
});
```

Comment: Not a bad theory.  I can try it to see.  I am pretty sure setting.name is the correct element name. But it may lose it's meaning inside the click function being defined.  I will give it a shot and do some debugging to see if that is the case.  Thanks

Comment: Oh jeez, I am an idiot.  Should be settings.name not settings.Name.  I knew it was something simple.  Thanks for you for your help

Comment: I think both of my alternatives would have worked as well

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it worked also.  I will mark this as correct since the issue stated was my problem.  I was calling the submit on an object that did not exist.  Thanks again.